# How to open (expand) block element to the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

lets say I have 2 block elements that have fixed position and look like this in a window:

```
--------------
|        xxx |
|        xxx |
|            |
|        xxx |
|        xxx |
|            |
--------------
```

I want an element to expand to the left on hover, like this:

```
--------------
|        xxx |
|        xxx |
|            |
|     xxxxxx |
|     xxxxxx |
|            |
--------------
```

However, right now it expands to the right. Working example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/eeuho5vq/2/

Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: btw you don't need js to expand it on hover. Just use pseudo `:hover` css-selector

Comment: @Stalinko yeah I know, its just that in my original code I need to do other things while on hover that do need js :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-end;` on the parent and that align the elements to the right.

```js
 $(".container").each(function(){
  $(this).hover(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("show");
  })
 })
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.container {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.container.show {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <!--element 1-->
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <!--element 2-->
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to `.container`:

```
  float: right;
  clear: both;
```

Updated snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/eeuho5vq/3/